# What are the first four 'anon' sections in a JVM pmap?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I understand that there are many different places where out-of-JVM-heap memory gets allocated: thread stacks, memory mapped files (e.g. zip files), NIO buffers, allocations by JNI libraries etc.

But I'm hoping that there is a canonical identification of the first four allocations, e.g.:

```
/apps/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ...
0000000000400000      4K r-x--  /apps/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java
0000000000600000      4K rw---  /apps/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java
0000000001e69000 280920K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000b0000000 132288K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000b8130000 129856K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000c0000000 1048576K rw---    [ anon ]
00000030b4e00000    120K r-x--  /lib64/ld-2.12.so
...
```

I think the last one is likely to be the heap, based on its size, but does anyone know what the other three are? It would be helpful to be able to identify as many `anon` sections as possible for diagnostic purposes.